# react-native - Upgrading to Gradle 7 breaks project

Tags: react-native, gradle

react-native: 0.66.4
Upgraded:

- Gradle Plugin from 4.2.2 to 7.0.2
- Gradle from 6.9.0 to 7.2.0

When running react-native run-android got:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/Users/chen.oppenhaim/dev/toluna-mobile-app/mobile-apps/node_modules/react-native-rate/android/build.gradle' line: 41

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-rate'.
> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.
```

Its seems that now one of my react-native packages (react-native-rate) is not compatible with Gradle 7.
I guess that once I fixed this issue - other packages as well will have incompatibilities issues as well.

How should I approach this issue?

android/build.gradle (Gradle plugin version):

```
buildscript {
   dependencies {
       classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2')
   }
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties (Gradle version):

```
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
```

Comment: Gradle has documentation for upgrading from older versions, for example [here are the docs for upgrading from 6.x to 7](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html).

Comment: Thanks @aSemy - the context here is how to deal with incompatibility of react native packages with Gradle 7

Comment: Sorry, have I misunderstood what the problem you're facing is? Could you update your question to include your `build.gradle`, and link to the Gradle plugins you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it.

Those Gradle plugin and Gradle upgrades are possible in react-native project but keep in mind that other react-native packages in your project might not be compatible with Gradle 7.

Specific for the error I got - upgrading react-native-rate to latest version solve the issue - but it was not the only upgrade I needed to do - so you can expect that (overall 4 upgrades).

Also not sure What I gain from this Gradle upgrade but this is another discussion.